# Rails cross browser testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, cucumber

I have created a rails online form application and now would like to automate the cross browser and multi tablet and mobile device browser testing.

I was thinking of writing a cucumber script and then use Selenium? Is this the best way forward?

Comment: A longshot: You might want to check out http://www.browserling.com or http://ci.testling.com/